# Create a time series plot with month and year on x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have created a DataFrame with Date (format = 1950-01-01) as the index, unemployment rate and a binary variable for recession (True = recession). I am trying to plot the data as a time series with month and year both on the x-axis. Right now it only displays year.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5)) 
df1.plot(y='UNRATE',ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Additionally, I am supposed to shade in the months in which there was a recession. I use `ax.axvspan()` which takes x-start and x-ends as arguments for where to shade. However there's a problem with my code for 'starts' and 'ends' - I think it has something to do with the months but I'm not sure. If anyone could help me out with this too it would be amazing! Thank you!

```
starts = df1['USREC']==True
ends = df1['USREC']==False

n = len(df1)
for i in range(1,n):
    ax.axvspan(starts[i], ends[i], facecolor='lightgray')
```

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Does this help? It's the output when I print df1.head()   
DATE: 1950-01-01  , 1950-02-01  , 1950-03-01  , 1950-04-01 , 1950-05-01
UNRATE: 6.5 , 6.4 , 6.3 , 5.8 , 5.5
USREC: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

Comment: Not really, a minimal example should be easy to copy in order to reproduce the issue

Comment: I edited the comment, you should be able to recreate part of the dataframe with it. I guess I'm not understanding what other information you would need... Thank you for trying though!

Comment: I provided a solution, thus you can see what a MRE is (no need to reconstruct anything, just copy and run) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a minimal working example. There are probably much better ways to do it, but I kept a version as close as possible to your original code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': ['1950-01-01', '1950-02-01', '1950-03-01', '1950-04-01', '1950-05-01'],
                    'UNRATE': [6.5, 6.4, 6.3, 5.8, 5.5],
                    'USREC': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
                   })
df1['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5)) 
df1.plot(x='DATE', y='UNRATE', ax=ax)

starts = df1['USREC']==True
ends = df1['USREC']==False

for i, r in df1.iterrows():
    if r['USREC'] == 1:
        ax.axvspan(r['DATE'], r['DATE']+pd.Timedelta('31d'), facecolor='lightgray')
```

output:

[image: matplotlib line plot with spans]